# iText 7 relative column width no longer working starting iText 7.0.2

Tags: itext7

I am having problems setting relative column widths for a table in iText 7.0.4. I tried Bruno's example code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41428692/8804951. If I execute the example with iText 7.0.1 I get exactly the result from Bruno's answer:

[image: PDF created with iText 7.0.1]

but for later versions the result looks like this:

[image: PDF created with iText 7.0.2]

The original example on the iText web page does not seem to reflect this change in behaviour yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table layout algoritm changed in version 7.0.2 as is stated in the API docs (http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/latest/com/itextpdf/layout/element/Table.html#Table-float:A-boolean-). The simplest solution is to add a second parameter with the value `true` to the constructor of `Table`:

```
Table htable = new Table(new float[] {3, 8, 5, 10, 5, 10, 30}, true);
```

The one-parameter version of the constructor now takes absolute column widths in points.

Comment: Alternatively, pass a `UnitValue[]` containing percent unit values. You can create one from a float array using `UnitValue.createPercentArray()`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for setting the column width in itext-7.1.3 ., you can try this.

```
Table content = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(new float[]{3,5,10}));
content.setWidth(UnitValue.createPercentValue(100));
content.setFixedLayout();
```